# Wireless router URL redirection

Tags: networking, router, redirect, wifi, url

I'm trying to "filter" explicit URLs (+18/21) from network traffic and redirect to another website. I have physical access to router inside my home, computer and router local web-access, which let's say does not support Captive portal and is not DD-WRT supported. My router is also not Cisco just to note.

Is there any other way I can filter URLs, but make sure that user is redirected to another website and not just have blocked access (by router settings). So what I'm actually trying to achieve is to make wireless user be redirected on every particular URL to constant pre-defined URL. I though maybe about OS firewalls or URL blockers but I don't know which software has a wireless URL redirection options.

Here is the basic graph-image of network configuration I have to implement:
IMAGE- https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsnlb.png

Any advices are appreciated. Thanks and regards everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could setup BIND or other DNS server inside your network, and setup your router to use your DNS server for DHCP clients. Then use DNS to redirect domains through CNAME records to your specified redirect domain. If there is a machine or set of machines that you don't want this DNS redirect to happen on, specify other/external DNS servers on these machines manually so that they won't be redirected.

Comment: That was exactly what I need. Didn't come of that idea. Going to work on it tomorrow, thanks for your time. Any tips you can give me?